# Unit testing Decodable: what's your approach for invalid data?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

Let's say you have a JSON with several fields:

```
Students: [
  student: {
    name: "Harry"
    surname: "Smith"
    age: 24
  },
 ...
]
```

and decodables:

```
struct Students : Decodable {
    let student: [Student]
}

struct Student : Decodable {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let age: Int
}
```

If you want to test invalid data, do you write a sequence of tests with te following fake data?

Test1 data:

```
{
name: null
surname: "Smith"
age: 24
}
```

Test2 data:

```
{
name: "Harry"
surname: null
age: 24
}
```

Test3 data:

```
{
name: "Harry"
surname: "Smith"
age: null
}
```

And maybe a test with a wrong type?

```
{
name: "Harry"
surname: "Smith"
age: "24" //<- string
}
```

So do you write all these tests, one for each of the above jsons or does this not make sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd **primarily test the success way** with at least one case.

Also I'd test a few **cases with "borderline" values** like unusual characters in String values or Integer values around the 32/64bit threshold.

Finally I'd test for **one case where all the required (non-optional) values are null**. If you later change the model for some properties to be optional this test would fail so you can check if you need to make adaptions because of the changed circumstance.

Answer (score 4):

It makes sense writing separate test for each `key-value` pair if we were not able to see the reason of failure and we had to handle it ourself for each pair. For example, old way of `JSONSerialization` to get `Dictionary` and then manually checking each `key-value` if they exist, if yes, does type matches etc. If we were able to get all the values and expected then we would use to initialize the type e.g, `Student`. In this kind of scenario, instead of putting so many `if-else` to report proper failure one can think of separate cases for each pair.

Now that we have `Codable` and `error` thrown clearly provide all the information for failure so a single test is enough.

Answer (score 3):

The `Decodable` protocol provides a series of specific Decoding errors.

As already mentioned by Kamran use **one** test and catch all possible Decoding errors for example

```
do {
    XCTAssertNoThrow(try JSONDecoder().decode(Students.self, from: data))
} catch let DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context) {
    XCTFail("Data corrupted: \(context.debugDescription)")
} catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
    let message = "Key '\(key)' not found: \(context.debugDescription), codingPath: \(context.codingPath)"
    XCTFail(message)
} catch let DecodingError.valueNotFound(value, context) {
    let message = "Value '\(value)' not found: \(context.debugDescription), codingPath: \(context.codingPath)"
    XCTFail(message)
} catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)  {
    let message = "Type '\(type)' mismatch: \(context.debugDescription), codingPath: \(context.codingPath)"
    XCTFail(message)
} catch {
    XCTFail(error.localizedDescription)
}
```